# How to display the user email on account pages?

Tags: theming, users, emails

On the user account page all feilds are displayed except for the email. I have tried to modify the user-profile.tpl, and added

```
print $user->mail
```

but it displays the logged in user and not the account being displayed. Not a big problem since the end users usually only see their own account bit frustrating for admins. I also tried

```
print render($user_profile['mail']);
```

but that displays nothing.

Comment: Change to the default drupal theme to test if email gets displayed.

Comment: Upon further review, email is not in user manage fields. Therefore, you could go with [Adrian's answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188645/how-to-display-the-user-email-on-account-pages#answer-188651) or use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the following hook in the ***template.php*** of your theme:

```
/**
 * Process variables for user-profile.tpl.php.
 *
 * The $variables array contains the following arguments:
 * - $account
 *
 * @see user-profile.tpl.php
 */

function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_user_profile(&$variables) {
  $account = $variables['elements']['#account'];
  //Add mail to $user_profile variable
  $variables['user_profile']['mail'] = $account->mail;
  // Preprocess fields.
  field_attach_preprocess('user', $account, $variables['elements'], $variables);
}
```

And in your ***user-profile.tpl*** you can use:

```
print $user_profile['mail'];
```

Comment: Excellent. Works fine on the page that displays the account info, but the page that edits the data displays errors. Is the email added twice?
    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() i element_children() (rad 6540 av /storage/content/88/176188/rme.nu/public_html/includes/common.inc).

Comment: @Bosse I don't know try to debug with the devel dpm function